# Can Coded UI Test Agent and Test Controller communicate with ech other being on different networks

Tags: coded-ui-tests

We are trying to get Test Controller and Test Agent to communicate with each other and get Coded UI Test Scripts executed remotely. Given that both Test Agent and Test Controller are on machines on two different networks.

Can anyone suggest what needs to be done inorder to get it going, we have tried alot but were not able to get Test Agent Registered with Test Controller outside hetwork.

Answer (score 0):

The [Troubleshooting Guide](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/df043823-ffcf-46a4-9e47-1c4b8854ca13/troubleshooting-guide-for-visual-studio-test-controller-and-agent?forum=vststest) from Microsoft states

```
The technology used to connect remote test execution components is .Net Remoting over Tcp ports.
```

The network diagrams indicate that the two components need to be network reachable of each other. If they are not on the same network, you would need some sort of VPN or port forwarding solution. See also [the guide on configuring ports](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff652627.aspx).